# SP2019 - Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I'm facing a really strange behaviour in SharePoint 2019 Standard Server (in all three tiers!)
First things first: It's a SharePoint 2019 Standard Server (latest patches already installed) on a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter with SQL Server 2019 Standard in the background.

Generating the three farms (dev/test/prod) was fine and Central Administration is available as it should. Unfortunately every other Web Application that is created afterwards fires a "Service Unavailable - HTTP Error 503", regardless if the Web Application was created with a hostheader or not. I can't find any differences between those Websites/Application Pools in IIS. Besides the physical paths, IDs, etc., everything seems to be similar.
As of IIS Manager the websites are online, the application pools are started.

I don't know where to look at now. Maybe some of you might have any idea...

I already checked this page: http://sharepoint-wiese.de/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable/ and did all of the three mentioned steps (checking running state of application pools, membership of IIS_IUSRS user group, local security policies). Again: Everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

A few more things to check:

1. Make sure all SharePoint services are started under `Services.msc`.
2. Run the `SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard`.
3. Check System Event viewer / ULS logs when trying to access the issued web applications. See if you can get specific error message for this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately nothing helped me out. The ULS is clear of all error messages due to nothing came down to the SharePoint level. Something went really wrong on IIS Level. Even new created AppPools and Websites had the same error. My suggestion is, that the IIS (or some configs of it) may broke at some point without noticing it.
We decided to rebuild everything from scratch and it'S working fine so far.